# R libraries not loading using JRI in Java

Tags: java, r, jri

I am trying to read an excel using r in Java using JRI(JAVA R INTERFACE) but it is not working .I have listed some errors which I believe might be the reason-

1. R libraries not loaded properly.
2. Error in the file location(because of the separators).
3. Wrong method used for loading libraries.

THE CODE -

```
    package pkg;

    import java.io.File;

    import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
    import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
    public class Read {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Start Rengine.
    Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);




    //printing the packages in library
    System.out.println("R_HOME =" + System.getenv("R_HOME"));
      String path =System.getenv("R_HOME") + "\\library" ;
       File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
        }


    //calling required libraries
   String librarylocation= engine.eval(".libPaths()").asString();
   System.out.println("location of the R libraries:" + librarylocation);



   //to check whether engine is actually working
   Double d= engine.eval("x=mean(c(1,2,3))").asDouble();
   System.out.println("Mean obtained:" + d);


   //checking the working directory 
   String workingdirectory= engine.eval("getwd()").asString();
   System.out.println("location of the working directory:"+ workingdirectory);


   //R CODE TO READ EXCEL FILE (NOT WORKING)
   engine.eval("library(rJava)");
   engine.eval("library(xlsxjars)");
   engine.eval("library(xlsx)");
   engine.eval("library(Matrix)");
   engine.eval("excelfile<-read.xlsx(\"C:/Users/aakashs/Desktop/File_Parse/LT257-Refuel 3 March2017.xlsx\",sheetIndex=1,startRow=9,colIndex=c(1,2,3)");



    //PRINTING VALUE TO CHECK IF THE FILE WAS READ (NOT WORKING)       
    REXP data=engine.eval("excelfile[1,1]");
    System.out.println(" value in data frame:"+ data);



   //performing required operations (NOT WORKING BECAUSE OF ABOVE CODE)
   engine.eval("column4<-matrix(nrow(excelfile),1)");
   engine.eval("for(i in 1:(nrow(excelfile))){column4[i]=excelfile[i+1,3]-excelfile[i,3]}");
   engine.eval("column4<-data.frame(column4)");
   engine.eval("finaldata<-cbind(excelfile,column4)");


   //printing the created data frame(NULL OUTPUT)
   REXP datafinal = engine.eval(" finaldata");
   System.out.println("Data table is :" + datafinal);


   //Writing the data frame to an excel file(NO FILE CREATED )
   engine.eval("write.xlsx(finaldata,\"D:\\\\final2.xlsx\"");
   engine.eval("initial=paste('aakash','singhal')");

}

}
```

RESULT OBTAINED-

```
R_HOME =C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1
Directory base
Directory boot
Directory class
Directory cluster
Directory codetools
Directory compiler
Directory datasets
Directory df2json
Directory foreign
Directory graphics
Directory grDevices
Directory grid
Directory KernSmooth
Directory lattice
Directory MASS
Directory Matrix
Directory methods
Directory mgcv
Directory nlme
Directory nnet
Directory parallel
Directory rJava
Directory rjson
Directory rpart
Directory spatial
Directory splines
Directory stats
Directory stats4
Directory survival
Directory tcltk
Directory tools
Directory translations
Directory utils
Directory XLConnect
Directory XLConnectJars
Directory xlsx
Directory xlsxjars
location of the R libraries:C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library
Mean obtained:2.0
location of the working directory:D:/Eclipse/RandJava
value in data frame:null
Data table is :null
```

I have tried whatever was available on Stack regarding this issue but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to use R scripts in Java is to use it like a R function.
Make a R script and pass the arguments accordingly.It will also give more functionality to the code.

I haven't attached the whole code but writing all the engine.eval(Strings) in a R script and sourcing it in the code works perfectly.

Java -

```
engine.eval("source(\"testRun2.R\")");  
engine.eval("testrunfunction(filepath,filelocation)");
```

R-

```
testrunfunction<-function(filePath,filelocation)
{
library('rJava')
library('xlsxjars')
library('xlsx')
library('Matrix')
library('xlsx')
excelfile<-read.xlsx(filepath,sheetIndex=1,startRow=9,colIndex=c(1,2,3))
column4<-matrix(nrow(excelfile),1)
for(i in 1:(nrow(excelfile))){column4[i]=excelfile[i+1,3]-excelfile[i,3]}
column4<-data.frame(column4)
finaldata<-cbind(excelfile,column4)
write.xlsx(finaldata,filelocation)
}
```